# With Check Option Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, ddl

I have an ALTER TABLE statement, written in T-SQL (SQL Server):

```
ALTER TABLE myTable WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_myTable_myColumn] FOREIGN KEY(myColumn) REFERENCES otherTable (Column)
```

If I want to translate this statement in Postgresql, how can I make this? Paying attention to **WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT**

Answer (score 1):

You need to

- remove `WITH CHECK` - I don't know what this is supposed to do, but you can't have a "check constraint" together with a foreign key constraint in Postgres
- use standard compliant identifiers (without the square brackets)

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
   ADD  CONSTRAINT fk_mytable_mycolumn 
   FOREIGN KEY(my_column) REFERENCES other_table (column)
```